# Is it possible to keep a modeless form topmost always?

Tags: vb6

Is it possible to keep a form, etc. a find/replace form, topmost always when it is modeless?

Comment: An *owned window* is always on top of its owner and gets minimized when its owner is minimized.  Use the Show() method, 2nd argument to specify the owner.  IIRC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation on the `SetWindowsPos` api call is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx

Example code to include in your form:

```
Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
Const SWP_NOMOVE = 2
Const SWP_NOSIZE = 1
Const flags = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
Const HWND_TOP = 0
Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim lResult As Long
  lResult = SetWindowPos(Me.hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, flags)
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the answer which I looked for and which I found some other sources immadiately after I had asked here; thanks.